# How to implement $(this).stop(); in jqueryUI

Tags: jquery-ui

How to implement $(this).stop(); in jqueryUI

```
graph.hover(function() {
    wrap
    $(this).stop();
        .animate( { height: "hide" }, 2000, name )

},
function() {
    wrap
    $(this).stop();
    .animate( { height: "show" }, 2000, name );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this :

```
graph.hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate( { height: "hide" }, 2000, function(){//Callback})

},
function() {
    $(this).stop().animate( { height: "show" }, 2000, function(){//Callback});
});
```